# Querying Flink Dynamic table from external application

Tags: apache-flink

I have Flink job with Dynamic Table API. I want to query the result table from an external source/application like jdbc/rest api etc.
Kindly help out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is to materialize the result table somewhere by connecting a TableSink that stores the results and makes them available for querying. You might use the [JDBC](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#jdbc-connector) or [HBase](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#hbase-connector) connector, for example.

This is necessary because in general the "result table" doesn't really exist, as such. For queries that only involve projection and windowed aggregation, for example, the results stream out of Flink but aren't actually retained within Flink.